# Display contents in text file using ajax

Tags: ajax

I am new to using ajax (I am retaking my web engineering class this semester) and I am able to pull a text file from the server and am able to get it to display. It is displaying on my HTML page like this:

New York 8,143,197 Los Angeles 3,844,829 Chicago 2,842,518 ...

but i want it do display the cities in one column, and the population in another.

What can I do? I have also not learned about jquery yet.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc()  {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }

   // Get which country the user selected
   var radioArray = document.myForm.countries;
   var i;
   var value;

   for (i = 0; i < radioArray.length; i++) {
     if (radioArray[i].checked) {
       value = radioArray[i].value;
     }
   }

   if (value == "usa") {
     xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/~ercanbracks/usa.txt",true);
   }
   if (value == "canada") {
     xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/~ercanbracks/canada.txt",true);
   }
   if (value == "mexico") {
     xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/~ercanbracks/mexico.txt",true);
   }
   if (value == "russia") {
     xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/~ercanbracks/russia.txt",true);
   }
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>

 </head>
 <body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
 <h1>Most populated cities in the world!</h1>
 <form name="myForm" action="">
 <input type="radio" name="countries"
 onchange="loadXMLDoc()" value="usa" checked>USA
 <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="countries"
 onchange="loadXMLDoc()" value="canada">Canada
 <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="countries"
 onchange="loadXMLDoc()" value="mexico">Mexico
 <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="countries"
 onchange="loadXMLDoc()" value="russia">Russia
 </form>
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the whole response text to your element "myDiv" no matter what the response is. You need to first process the data from the response (xmlhttp.responseText) - in such way that you can separate city - population pairs, and based on how many rows of the pairs you get, you can for example create a new table element, and specify the rows and cells of the table.

```
            function loadXMLDoc()
            {
                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                else 
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        var dataToProcess = xmlhttp.responseText;

                        // process the data to get city-population pairs - assign them to an array for example
                        //...


                        // Create a new table element
                        var Table = document.createElement("Table");

                        // Foreach city-population pair, create one row and specify it's cells
                        for (var i = 0; i < YourArray.length; i++)
                        {
                            row             = Table.insertRow(i); 
                            cell1           = row.insertCell(0);
                            cell1.innerHTML = 'Your city value'; // YourArray[i]['City'];
                            cell2           = row.insertCell(1);
                            cell2.innerHTML = 'Your population value'; // YourArray[i]['Population'];
                        }

                        // Assign the table to a parent element
                        document.getElementById("your parent element").appendChild(Table);

                       // Be careful to which element you assign the new table element as a child, so that the page content don't need to be redrawn to make it visible
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you so much! That makes sense I didn't know you can do this. Thanks mbuster!

Comment: you can do anything you want to do with the returned data.. you're welcome ;)

Comment: I ended up just putting my code in a textarea tag. The txt file already had the columns in it, so I guess the textarea preserves the white space. I guess using a pre tag would work too.